# Why does this attribute work with parent class but give me an error with child class? Python on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: python, inheritance, raspberry-pi-zero

Base class:

```
class AtlasI2C:

    LONG_TIMEOUT_COMMANDS = ("R", "CAL")
    SLEEP_COMMANDS = ("SLEEP", )

    def __init__(self, address=98, moduletype = '', name = '', bus=1):
        '''
        open two file streams, one for reading and one for writing
        wb and rb indicate binary read and write
        '''
        self._address = address
        self.bus = bus 
        self.file_read = io.open(file="/dev/i2c-{}".format(self.bus), 
                                 mode="rb", 
                                 buffering=0)
        self.file_write = io.open(file="/dev/i2c-{}".format(self.bus),
                                  mode="wb", 
                                  buffering=0)
        self.set_i2c_address(self._address)
        self._name = name
        self._module = moduletype
```

When I instantiate this base class on the raspberry pi, It works perfectly.

However, when I try to instantiate the following child class, it gives me an error in self.

```
class EC_sensor(AtlasI2C):
    '''
    Used to initialise Atlas EC sensor. Sets specific attributes for this sensor. 
    '''
    def __init__(self, address=100, moduletype='EC', name='Atlas_EC_sensor', bus=1):
        super().__init__(moduletype, name, bus, address)
```

error:

```
File "testfile.py", line 17, in main
  device = EC_sensor()
File "/home/pi/sensors/EC_sensor.py", line 47, in __init__
  super().__init__(module type,name,bus, address)
File "/home/pi/sensors/AtlasI2C.py",line 33, in __init__
  buffering = 0)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directoryL: '/dev/i2c-100'
```

Why is this? Would self.file not automatically work the same way because it's inherited?

Comment: why do you mix the named value positions ?

Comment: Ah damn, silly error. That fixed it, thanks!